# Facebook Request Notification not showing in iOS mobile safari but in native facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, safari, facebook-requests

Use-case: I sent a request from my game to friend x. Friend x gets a notification in his native Facebook app, taps it and the game opens. If he opens the safari mobile page of Facebook the same notification is never shown.

Is there a way to enable request notifications to appear in the mobile website of facebook?

My game has an Facebook iOS App enabled, the bundle identifier is set and the Store ID is set.
The Facebook App runs in developement Mode.

Comment: Do you think you can be a bit more explicit? I think I'm not getting the problem

Comment: sure. everytime i send a friend request via my game, my friend should somehow be notified that a request was sent. this is handled by facebook with displaying the request in the notification bar. assuming you use the fb ios app to interact with facebook, you will see a notification inside the app. once you tap it it opens the game. now i want to do the same without the facebook app, but using the mobile website in the safari browser. the same notification should be displayed there, but in my case it doesn't.

Comment: ok... are you using URL schemes?

Answer (score 0):

well what i did to acomplish a similar result... Open my app from a button in an email...  is using URL Schemes..

basically everything you need to do is modify your info.plist file and then your are ready to go.

whenever the device sends a request for example myapp:// ... (from a browser, another app, etc.) ... then your app will show up

[image: here]

here is an image with an example.. hope it helps

GL HF